# Does holding a C++ reference prevents variable of being destroyed?

Tags: c++

Coming from a Java/C# background I am trying to implement kinda a null safety check object. The following code tries to check if there is indeed a color on the object. If there is, I want be able to do some stuff (like drawing the color on a shape). I want to be able to set this color back to null (noneColor), preventing for coloring the object.

I didn't want to set this color has a pointer, because it would be necessary to delete it on every setter and on the deconstructor. Is this a bad thought?

Code:

```
static const Color& noneColor = Color();

static bool isNoneColor(const Color& color) {
    return std::addressof(noneColor) == std::addressof(color);
}

MyShape:MyShape() {
    this->color = noneColor; // this->color is an object of Color
}

void MyShape::setColor(const Color& newColor)
{
    this->color= newColor;
}

void MyShape::draw()
{
    if(!isNoneColor(this->color))
        // Color shape
}

//different scope/class
void B::setColorForShape()
{
    Color color = Color(255,255,255);
    a->setColor(color);
    // Calling isNoneColor(a->color); should return false;
    // After this function ends does variable a->color have undefined behavior? 
}

void B::setNoneColorForShape()
{
    a->setColor(noneColor);
    //Calling isNoneColor(a->color); should return true;
}
```

Is it safe to call isNoneColor with a->color afterwards the method ends?

Edit:

`MyShape:color` is declared has `Color& color`. I want to be able to set a noneColor state on my object `MyShape`. With a simple Color object I can't know if that color is "null"/empty state.

Comment: _"I didn't want to set this color has a pointer, because it would be necessary to delete it on every setter and on the deconstructor."_ What do you mean by this?

Comment: How is the `MyShape::color` member variable declared?  It's hard to say with confidence how this code will behave when we don't know its type.

Comment: The way this code looks like `color` should be stored as a regular value, not as a reference. It's unclear what you are trying to do with "storing a reference"

Comment: `prevents variable of being destroyed` This may point to a misunderstanding about how C++ works. No variable is ever "destroyed" automatically, unless its lifetime ends by the language rules (e.g. a local variable goes out of scope), or you write code to explicitly "destroy" it.

Comment: "Does holding a C++ reference prevents variable of being destroyed?" - In *general*, no. In certain circumstances, a `const` reference can keep *temporary* objects alive. But no, a reference to an object does not keep that object alive.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner MyShape::color is declared as a Color& color;

Comment: I strongly suggest instead of your approach you consider using `std::optional<Color>` when you need a *no color present* state. That way you can use the type system to make a clear distinction between parts of your code that work with a maybe-color (and therefore have to check before use) and code working with a definite-color that does not need to check. Compilation will fail when you mess up. If you encode the maybe-state into the main type the compiler cannot help you anymore.

Comment: I see your confusion, you should stop thinking like a C# programmer about references and instead look at the C++ references as syntactic sugar for pointers which can't be reassign to point elsewhere nor be null

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` is the closest C++ equivalent to java references

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that

> MyShape::color is declared as a Color&

... the code is a bit problematic.

The thing to know about C++ references is that you can't *re-seat* them -- that is, unlike a C++ pointer, once a C++ reference is declared, it will always reference the object it was declared to reference, and cannot be re-directed to reference some other object instead.  (Btw this is also the reason why you're not allowed to declare an unbound reference, e.g. `MyColor & c;` won't compile because it would be useless)

From that, it follows that what this code actually does:

```
void MyShape::setColor(const Color& newColor)
{
   this->color= newColor;
}
```

is overwrite the contents of (whatever `Color` object `this->color` is referencing) with the contents of `newColor`).  It doesn't change the reference itself at all; rather it writes *through* the reference.  (Remember that references are defined as *aliases-to-something*, so wherever you specify the reference, the program will behave as if you had specified the object-the-reference-is-referencing there instead)

To answer the titular question:  holding a C++ reference does not guarantee that the object the reference is referencing will not be destroyed.  It's quite possible to delete (or otherwise destroy) the referenced item, and end up with a "dangling reference" that will invoke Undefined Behavior if you try to use it.

As general advice, if you want to have a guard-value to represent "no-color", the best way to do it is to represent the guard-value as an actual color object (e.g. `Color(0,0,0,0)` could work, if your `Color` class has an alpha-channel, since any color with alpha=0 is transparent, hence no-color).  That way there is no need to play games with pointers or references to try to represent that information.  If that's not doable for some reason, have a look at [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) as a way to represent "either-a-value-or-nothing".

As a final note, using pointers does not mean you have to use `new` and `delete` -- pointers work equally well (and you can shoot yourself in the foot with them equally badly) when they are pointing to stack-objects or member-objects.  Which is to say, pointers are very powerful, and also very dangerous, and I wouldn't recommend using them for this purpose.

Comment: As a side note, we use std::unique_ptr if a pointer has ownership, no more calling of delete needed

Comment: @JVApen that would work, but for a trivially small class like `Color` I think it would be better not to make use of the heap at all, and rather just do all operations by-value.

Comment: Agreed with that, I just wanted to point it out as the question gives me the impression the OP has a lot to (re)learn about ownership/storage in C++, mentioning new/delete was definitely good, however it's one of elements which makes C++ difficult, although C++11 made that much easier

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question

> Does holding a C++ reference prevents variable of being destroyed?

is: not generally, but in this case, **yes**. The [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) has this to say

> 4. There are two contexts in which **temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the full-expression**. The first context is [..]
> 5. The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. **The temporary to which the reference is bound** or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound **persists for the lifetime of the reference** *except*:
>
>    - A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s ctor-initializer(12.6.2) persists until the constructor exits.
>    - A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call.
>    - The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement (6.6.3) is not extended; the temporary is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in the return statement.
>    - A temporary bound to a reference in a new-initializer(5.3.4) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the new-initializer. [Example][Note]

(*from 12.2 `[class.temporary]`, emphasis added, example and note omitted*)

---

Although this is a bad practice, and something like `T const& t = T();` will look odd to many C++ programmers (I presume), it is technically legal. It's usefulness can be debated, as `T const t = T();` will do the same job without looking odd. See [Jeremy Friesner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62073750/430766)'s answer for why your approach will not work as expected because references cannot be *re-seated*.

Answer (score -1):

> Does holding a C++ reference prevents variable of being destroyed?

In general no, not in the way Java references prevent variables from being destroyed.

The lifetime of an object is determined by their storage class: Lifetime of automatic object ends when executions goes out of the block where the variable was declared, lifetime of dynamic object ends when it is deleted, lifetime of static object ends when the process terminates. Lifetime of temporary object ends at the end of the full-expression where it was created, <sub>except in special case of binding temporary to a reference, in which case the lifetime of the temporary object ends when the lifetime of the reference ends. And only that one reference; No other reference affects the lifetime of the said temporary object. This is useful in generic programming because it allows certain objects to be treated as if they were references.</sub>

`isNoneColor` can never return true for a member of `MyShape` <strike>because such member will always have different address than `noneColor`.</strike>

Edit: Above was written with the reasonable assumption that the member is an object of type `Color`

> Edit:
>
> MyShape:color is declared has Color& color.

In this case, the member cannot refer to `noneColor` because a reference to non-const cannot be bound to the lvalue referred by a reference to const... Unless you use const_cast, but that would be naughty.

Comment: I am passing the variable by address on function setColor, shouldn't that be enough to return true when i call isNoneColor after setColor(noneColor)?

Comment: If you pass the argument to `isNoneColor`. But you don't do that in the function.

Comment: Your "No" is [incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62074608/430766). I admit that I almost didn't trust my eyes, but binding a reference to a temporary does, indeed, extend its lifetime. I agree that it *shouldn't*, but it *does*.

Comment: @bitmask I wanted to not mention that special case. It is not something that is useful to a beginner, and has a danger of introducing bugs due to misunderstanding of when it applies. It may be especially confusing to  Java programmer such as OP, because in Java the lifetime of all objects is determined by references that point to them.

Comment: I don't share the philosophy that lying to beginners is the best way to protect them. Let alone teach them.

Comment: @bitmask Then we disagree. I prefer I breadth first, top-down approach to learning and teaching languages rather than depth first, bottom-up approach. Its not always necessary to explain every exception, and exception of exception when those are not yet useful to the beginner, except in cases where not knowing about them may lead to bugs. I've now included this special case in the answer, for better or worse.